# iframe and hiding elements

Tags: css, iframe

Is there anyway to control elements shown in an iframe? for example I am loading in a page in an iframe from google docs viewer which has controls for the user to navigate but I don't want these shown in my iframe...is there anyway to control this if I know the css id of this particular section?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do will not work out. As koenp said, you have limited influence on the element in the iframe when it's loaded from the same domain.
But if you have the document on the same domain, then it makes ablsoutely no sense to use an iframe. Then you better use ajax to have better control and influence over the document.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works if you use JQuery

```
$('#iframeId').find('#divIdInTheIframe').show();
```

Although the src of the iframe must be of the same origin as the wrapper page (same domain).